# Knife Party - Destroy Them With.. Lasers or Lazers?

Tags: electronic-music, song-title

I'm building a website which builds Spotify playlists from Last.FM data.
Knife Party - Destroy Them With Lasers/Lazers is one issue I'm trying to work out..

Last.FM spells Laser with a "z" ([and redirects "s" to "z"](https://www.last.fm/music/Knife+Party/_/Destroy+Them+With+Lasers)).

Spotify spells Laser with an "s" and cannot find Last.FM's spelling variant.

Which one is correct? (or which website is wrong?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knife Partys official YouTube channel lists the song name as "Destroy Them With Lazers" making Last.FM the correct spelling.